# How do I use Period in Route in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm trying to have a route in symfony that matches the following url:

`/filename/version/`

where filename is an image, say "image.png" and version as say "foo".

```
MyImageBundle_resize:
    pattern: /{filename}/{sizename}/
    defaults: { _controller: MyImageBundle:ImageResize:resize }
```

and this matchs the pattern `/myfile/XXL/`, for example. But when I use myfile.jpg, as in `/myfile.jpg/XXL/` Symfony seems to break on the period, and returns 404. I found this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html) which suggests that everything except the "/" will match (which doesn't make any sense if the period is breaking here).

Is there a way I can have the route match on the period?

Comment: Is it a Symfony-generated 404 or the standard web server 404? I'm just wondering if it's an .htaccess or nginx rule conflicting somewhere.

Comment: I'm running `php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev --watch` so not apache/nginx related imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to allow slash in URL. Just use simple route:

```
file_check:
    pattern:  /check/{filename}/{version}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:File:check }
```

And in your controller use:

```php
public function checkAction($filename, $version)
{
    //some action
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to essentially say that's what I used (unless I'm missing something). I'm getting a 404 in your example if my filename is "myfile.jpg", for example.

Comment: Then it's not caused by Symfony, but by environment. For me this is working fine.

Comment: You are right - it was the built in web server of PHP 5.4 that was throwing the error!